# Speed up query that returns results when present in one table but not in another

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. t1 contains business info and t2 contains business hours.
I use the following query to return results where data is present in t1 and is not in t2.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.id)
t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.id = t2.busId)
WHERE t2.busId IS NULL
```

This query works, but with about 15K records in t1 and 50K rows in t2 this literally takes minutes to return results. I wonder if it's possible to speed it up.

Comment: Have you tested with NOT EXISTS query? I am not sure about the result but you can test and compare with current result.

Comment: Minutes?? I have 1m and it takes 0.66 sec

Comment: We cannot tell you what is wrong exactly, because both the explain output (write `explain ` directly infront of your query) and the table descriptions (`show create table t2`) are missing. My best guess is that you do not have an index on `t2.busid`. Also, assuming `t1.id` is the primary key, you do not need `distinct`, as since you only look for rows that *do not* `left join`, they will not join with anything and so each id will only exists once anyway.

Comment: @Solarflare I think you were right about indexes. I've added PRIMARY KEY to t2.id and KEY to t.2busId and removed some key from t1 not ID but other column that should've not been there al;l together and now my results are returned almost instantaneously. I'd like to learn more about best practices in KEY setup. Is there a simple primer written in layman's terms? Thanks.

Comment: in addition to the comment above by Solarflare: Please note that `distinct` is **NOT a function** and that while you have used `DISTINCT(t1.id)` those parentheses are simply ignored. Instead `DISTINCT` is a qualifier to `SELECT ` (producing `SELECT DISTINCT` ) and this applies to the entire row, not just the column(s) listed within parentheses if used.